# Python - printing strings that exists in 2 files

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have 2 files containing multiple strings, `fileA.txt` and `fileB.txt`.

> fileA.txt:

```
hello hi 
how
```

> fileB.txt:

```
hello how are you
```

I am trying to write a program that will see if a string exists in both files. If it does, print the string or multiple strings.

The results would print "hello", and "how" as they exist in both files.

I am having trouble executing this as I have only been able to work with strings that I define, rather than unknown strings in the file:

```
with open("fileA.txt", 'r') as fileA, open ("fileB.txt") as fileB:
    for stringsA in fileA:

        for stringsB in fileB:

            if stringsA in stringsB:
                print("true")
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Files iterate by *lines*, not *words*.  You'll have to split the words:

```
>>> with open('fileA.txt') as a, open('fileB.txt') as b:
...     a_words = set(a.read().split())
...     b_words = set(b.read().split())
...     print('\n'.join(a_words & b_words))
...     
hello
how
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to construct a list of distinct words for each file and check for common words.

Python's Set datatype would be very helpful in this case.
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set

Answer (score 1):

You first want to get a list of all unique strings in `fileA`.  Then get a similar unique list for `fileB`.  Then compare the two.  Using `set`'s makes the comparison easier.

```
def get_strings_from_file(f):
    return set([s.strip() for s in f.read().split() if s.strip()])

def main():
    with open("fileA.txt", 'r') as fileA, open ("fileB.txt") as fileB:
        stringsA = get_strings_from_file(fileA)
        stringsB = get_strings_from_file(fileB)
        return stringsA.intersection(stringsB)
```

Comment: Thanks for this input!